# How to set to NULL a datetime with 0000-00-00 00:00:00 value?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, null, sql-update

I need to change a few values on my DB.

I forgot to set nullable to the table and it set to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 by default.

Now I need to convert that value in `NULL`.

The field type is Datetime.

How can I do it?

I try with the typical `Update table set field = NULL WHERE field = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to first make the column nullable:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY COLUMN field DATETIME NULL;
```

And then update the values:

```
UPDATE mytable SET field = NULL WHERE field = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Comment: Nullable is setted in symfony2

Comment: Look at answer from @AlterPHP for MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 12):

From MySQL 5.7, SQL mode NO_ZERO_DATE makes this update impossible unless you firstly disable this restriction (for the duration of the transaction only).

```
SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,"NO_ZERO_DATE", ""));
UPDATE mytable SET field = NULL WHERE field = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to first make the column nullable:

@Mysql5.7

**Wrong :**

```
update episodes set `ending` = NULL WHERE `ending` = '0000-00-00'
```

**Correct :**

```
update episodes set `ending` = NULL WHERE `ending` = 0000-00-00
```

Note: Remove the quote from the date value in your where clause. Hope it help someone

Comment: are you sure? I mean are you sure it's not the same (just in case it is working)? :)

Comment: What mysql version are you using

Comment: Since dates in databases are stored as integers, you can simply set `UPDATE episodes SET ending = NULL WHERE ending = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this will not work.
for:

```
update episodes set `ending` = NULL 
WHERE `ending` = '0000-00-00'
```

If `0000-00-00` is in the where clause, you get the error:

> "1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00' for column 'ending' at
> row 1".

even if `ending` has `NULL` and `default=null` in field definition.

Comment: This is an older question: If your answer is due to using a much newer version of mySQL software than state version number in your answer. Now it looks silly because the correct/best answer was given more than2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

1. Set the field from datetime to varchar(191).
2. Update all rows with field = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' to NULL.
3. Set the field back to datetime.